# Low quality question with absolutely irrelevant code generates large amount of upvotes

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Today I encountered a strange [low quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28534622/1090562). The question as it was worded in the beginning (you can see the history) had zero meaning, but even at that time it got an upvote. Trying to show a correct direction for the OP, I figured out that he has zero knowledge of what he wanted to achieve and only needed code.

At that time I decided to stop and told the poster that this site expects people to make some effort, and is not a free coding service. So the person just decided to throw in some absolutely irrelevant code to show that he has done something.

What surprises me is that this question steadily generates upvotes (in a tag where it is pretty hard to get upvotes), which makes me suspicious that something is wrong here. Is there any way to investigate the behaviour?

Comment: @Makoto: It is. I would be wary of any low-quality post that gained more than a couple of upvotes in such a short period of time.

Comment: @BoltClock:  I'll give you that.  I admit that I hadn't looked too closely at the history of the question, but now that I have looked a lot closer, this does feel a bit odd.  It could also be a fluke; three users within an hour of each other could have seen this question and thought that it was something to upvote for *whatever* reason.

Comment: @Makoto in mongo tag now even with pretty well researched question it is super hard to get 3 upvotes per day (I am constantly answering mongo questions, so I have some prior experience). For a junk question with 0 research, absolutely irrelevant code (everyone who spent at least hour reading about mongodb, sees that in that question OP just throws random SQL command) and with 20 views, generating 3 upvotes is super strange.

Comment: @SalvadorDali  note that the question is also tagged with C# - so it have potential to be seen by huge number of people... Presence of even semi-related code is not exactly normal thing for many C# questions so one could upvoted it just for that... Down-vote/vote to close and move on. From personal expirience "help me i need code" questions can't be recovered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Voting fraud of any sort is handled by moderators. If you suspect that the upvotes a low-quality question is getting are not legitimate, you can flag it for our attention. There is nothing else that a regular user can or should do beyond voting on the post for what it is.

Note that the user in question has only one post, so it will be difficult, if at all possible, for moderators to determine if anyone is voting based on the person and not the post or if the upvoters are just sympathetic or quality-blind. That said, we have other ways to figure out if e.g. someone is using multiple accounts or if there are other users who may be related to them in some way, which may or may not point to a larger issue.

Just remember that flagging something suspicious does not guarantee that action will be taken, since we can't take any action if we can't find concrete evidence of anything shady. It does however guarantee that the situation will be looked into.

Comment: flaggin it is not seems a good option, since declined flags may cause flag ban. Suspecting and flagging it, may damage to flagger.

Comment: @GLHF: FWIW, a single declined flag isn't going to get you immediately banned. But if flagging makes you so uncomfortable, you are free to just ignore the problems and focus on asking and answering questions. We have no shortage of users who are willing to help us by raising issues.